# How do I do subtraction with Hexadecimal numbers in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hexadecimal

I just want to do this operation in Excel and the other cells: 0155CDC5-25F9C52=
I don't want to use HEX2DEC then display the result in hexadecimal format, use the DEC2HEX function.
thanks

Comment: i found this in chatgpt also not works  :/: 
Set the Custom Format:
In the "Type" field on the right, enter a custom number format that indicates the cell should be treated as hexadecimal. For example, you can use the format "0x"0:

Comment: ChatGPT is famously unreliable. It is a chatbot, not a source of accurate information. It will lie through its teeth, quite convincingly. It could be described as a scourge of misinformation. Of course, you could always **test** what it tells you - that way you'd know for sure if it was hallucinating or not. If it  turns out to be telling the truth, then you can use it as the basis [**not** copy/paste] of your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

There is no other way.

Excel sees hex as strings not numbers. It will only do math on decimal. without converting, Excel is not the proper tool.

So the method is to change the Hex to Decimal and then do the math and change the resulting decimal back to Hexadecimal.

```
=DEC2HEX(HEX2DEC("0155CDC5")-HEX2DEC("25F9C52"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a simple UDF function (in a standard module):

```
Function DiffHex(A As String, B As String) As String
   DiffHex = Hex$(Val("&H" & A) - Val("&H" & B))
End Function
```

Then in Excel sheet you can write:

```
=DiffHex("0155CDC5","25F9C52")
```

The result is max 16 hex digits long.